# Adding dynamic notifications on android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, notifications, android-notifications

I want to add dynamic content on an andriod notification which can be updated with GCM or an API endpoint. Is it possible to show a dynamic google maps by hitting the google maps api on a notification. This picture(or an active google maps) should show up on the notification and should update itself as we pass new data to the notification. I am pretty new to the android world, so just got started with a basic notification app, can some one give me a few pointers to achieve my feature please.

Can I make a http request from an android notification to get data ?

Google maps API- http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap     size=512x512&maptype=roadmap\&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7CSan+Francisco,CA%7COakland,CA%7CSan+Jose,CA&sensor=false

```
protected void displayNotification() {
      Log.i("Start", "notification");

  /* Invoking the default notification service */
    NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message");
    mBuilder.setContentText("You've received new message.");
    mBuilder.setTicker("New Message Alert!");
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mario);

  /* Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives */
    mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);


    /* adding multiple notifications

     */

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    String[] events = new String[6];
    events[0] = new String("You are now 5 mins away from the restaurant....");
    events[1] = new String("This is second line...");
    events[2] = new String("This is third line...");
    events[3] = new String("This is 4th line...");
    events[4] = new String("This is 5th line...");
    events[5] = new String("This is 6th line...");

    // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Big Title Details:");
    // Moves events into the big view
    for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

        inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
    }
    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);




  /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationView.class);

  /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
}
```